# openflow simulation on captured network traffic

Tags: openflow

I have captured network traffic on a router and I wanted to replay these packets on an OpenFlow simulator to understand flows behaviors. Is there any simulators/tools that will help me to achieve this?.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mininet. It can create virtual openflow switches. construct virtual topologies. so you can simulate your tasks there.

Comment: Yes I tried mininet but I could not achieve what I wanted. Therefore I built a simulator.